# Developing a remote appllication like ammyy in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to design an C# application Like Ammyy. Which will control the machine remotely over internet also. Basically default RDP only for the LAN env. But I want it for the internet scenario also. Please help and provide the code for the same.

Comment: Ask Ammyy people. And before that, read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software

Comment: So you are looking for someone to give you the code for what will be a fairly complex application so you can publish the application as your own?

Comment: but seriously, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Seeing this is your first post, let me point you towards out [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and offer some suggestions.  The community is generally very eager to help those that help themselves.  Questions should be practical, answerable, and show some research effort including letting us know what you have tried and why you are stuck.  `Please provide the code` requests without any and all of the above usually results in closed and/or deleted questions.  I would strongly suggest you edit your question to make it more focus and show your research

Comment: I'll do it if you transfer 1 Million USD to my account :-)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how much you will succeed. But to start with...

RDP on LAN knows which system its connecting to within the private network, which is trusted (either the local IP or the system name will do).
For RDP on internet, the system which you are connecting to should have a static IP address.

For both the scenario, the target system should be enabled to accept remote connections.

Since you are targeting for internet, either the target system should have a public IP or you can create a server application which will have registered systems to talk to. Much like a chat server.

Your app should be installed on both the systems. (source & target)
Your app should do a handshake first to talk to each other, some kind of authentication (Windows logon from remote ?).
For the source to do actions/execute commands on the target computer (not sure how its done in RDP), you have to break your head :). May be you can capture mouse and keyboard events and the coordinates and execute the same on target system.

This is just a rough idea.